# using getdefaultsharedpreferences in class extending Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

Hi I'm trying to set up an app where some of the values stored in sharedPreferences are reset on a weekly basis. 
I have set up Alarm Manager to begin when a button is clicked as follows:

```
public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, OnClickListener {

Button button;
Toast mToast;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.prefsbuttons);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrefButton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().
registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);


 }

 protected void onDestroy() {
 getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().
unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

 @overide
 super.onDestroy();
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.bPrefButton:
     Intent intent = new Intent(EditPreferences.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EditPreferences.this,
             0, intent, 0);
    SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("savedFlash23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedFlash4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedFlash5", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean5", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog5", 0);
    editor.commit();

     // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
     long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
     firstTime += 15*1000;

     // Schedule the alarm!
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                     firstTime, 15*1000, sender);

     // Tell the user about what we did.
     if (mToast != null) {
         mToast.cancel();
     }

     mToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "first toast message",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     mToast.show();
 }


}



 }
```

The toast message displays and the shared preferences are reset.

The intent is passed to the Listener's class where I have the following code:

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "repeat toast message",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SharedPreferences userPrefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("savedFlash23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedFlash4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedFlash5", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedClean5", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog23", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog4", 0);
    editor.putInt("savedDog5", 0);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Toast message is getting displayed but the values in my shared preferences no longer get reset.

Comment: arent you doing the saame thing in both bPrefButton click and Onrecieve? how did you check the reset?

Comment: I've decided to work around the issue by launching an intent to a new class and clearing the values here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be not to try and do some much in a Broadcast receiver. I have used the following code to launch a new intent, which opens a class extending Activity where the shared preferences can be accessed as normal.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Reset.class);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
```